# How to select rows with column containing provided values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hi all consider following as my table structure

```
Col1   Col2 Col3 
A       1    Aa
A       2    Bb
A       1    Aa
A       4    Bb
B       2    Bb
C       1    Aa
C       5    Bb
D       3    Aa
```

As you can see Col3 contains distint values of Aa and Bb.

I am trying to write a query which return only rows with Col1 having value Aa and Bb (Both) or Aa(Alone).

Point is to remove those rows which have only have Bb associated with distinct Col1 value to it.

Example - For Col1 Distinct value of A should have Aa and Bb / Aa in corresponding Col3. This requirement is violated by value of B in Col1, hence result set should not have rows associated with B.

Expected output -

```
Col1   Col2 Col3 
A       1    Aa
A       2    Bb
A       1    Aa
A       4    Bb
C       1    Aa
C       5    Bb
D       3    Aa
```

Comment: I think I'm more confused by how you worded your question than what you're trying to accomplish. How can Col1 have a value of Aa when in your example it only has single character values???

Comment: I just edited my words to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName T 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM TableName
               WHERE T.Col1 = Col1 
                AND  Col3 = 'Aa')
```

Comment: Thank You it works perfectly, Can you explain this query a little bit.
Just for a stretch, what if i want only those values which has both Aa and Bb only. Then what modification to query will work?

Answer (score 2):

One other approach is to use `intersect` and `union`.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/878b2/3)

```
select * from t where col1 in (
select col1 from t where col3 = 'Aa'
intersect
select col1 from t where col3 = 'Bb'
union 
select col1 from t where col3 = 'Aa')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, using your values instead of a table.:

```
Select
T.*
From
(Select
    'A' As Col1, 1 As Col2, 'Aa' As Col3
Union All
Select
    'A', 2, 'Bb'
Union All
Select
    'A',1,'Aa'
Union All
Select
'A',4,'Bb'
Union All
Select
'B',2,'Bb'
Union All
Select
'C',1,'Aa'
Union All
Select
'C',5,'Bb'
Union All
Select
'D',3,'Aa'
) T
Inner Join
(Select
    Col1
    ,Sum(Case When Col3 = 'Aa' Then 1 Else 0 End) As CountAa
From
    (Select
        'A' As Col1, 1 As Col2, 'Aa' As Col3
    Union All
    Select
        'A', 2, 'Bb'
    Union All
    Select
        'A',1,'Aa'
    Union All
    Select
    'A',4,'Bb'
    Union All
    Select
    'B',2,'Bb'
    Union All
    Select
    'C',1,'Aa'
    Union All
    Select
    'C',5,'Bb'
    Union All
    Select
    'D',3,'Aa'
    ) T2
Group By
    Col1
) T3 On T.Col1 = T3.Col1
Where
T3.CountAa > 0
```

Simplified with a table, thats:

```
Select
T.*
From
YourTable T
Inner Join
(Select
    Col1
    ,Sum(Case When Col3 = 'Aa' Then 1 Else 0 End) As CountAa
From
    YourTable T2
Group By
    Col1
) T3 On T.Col1 = T3.Col1
Where
T3.CountAa > 0
```

The nice thing about this method is that you can add in lots of conditions in that case statement on a more complicated data set.

Comment: Thanks but it will a cumbersome job to do for million rows

Comment: I can't think of a single real world situation where hard coding out 30+ lines of sql would beat the answer already provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select table1.Col1, table1.Col2, table1.Col3
From Table1
join (SELECT Col1
        ,SUM(case when col3 = 'Aa' then 1 when Col3 = 'Bb' then 0 end) AS  [Counting]
        FROM [dbo].[Table1]
        group by Col1
        having SUM(case when col3 = 'Aa' then 1 when Col3 = 'Bb' then 0 end) > 0) keep on table1.Col1 = keep.Col1
```

Comment: Can you explain how is this different/better than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your actual data looks like, `row_number()` may be another possibility:

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3
from (
  select *, i = row_number() over(partition by Col1 order by Col1, Col3)
  from TableName
) a
where i > 1 or Col3 like 'Aa'
```